# Какова грамматика этого предложения?

Tags: запятые, синтаксис, тире, смысл

"Ну, я встал в шесть утра, это удивительно, ведь свой режим я толком и не наладил". Предложение не моё.

Comment: Я встал. Это удивительно. Я не наладил.

Comment: Про стилистику и знаки что-нибудь скажите. Монотонное изложение текста.  Как бы вы записали?  Кстати, я бы спросила так: Какова грамматика этого предложения?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Ну, **я встал** в шесть утра, **это удивительно**, ведь свой режим **я** толком и **не наладил**.*

1. Здесь **три** предикативные основы: *я встал, это удивительно, я не наладил.* Отношения между первым и вторым предложением взаимообусловленные, поэтому лучше использовать подчинительную связь.
2. Предложение можно **редактировать** так:

*Ну, я встал в шесть утра, **что** удивительно — ведь свой режим я толком и не наладил.*

Получится **два блока** [по Лопатину](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=136#pp136).

**Первый блок**: СПП с придаточным присоединительным, ***ЧТО*** — союзное слово (оно вмещает содержание главного предложения). **Второй блок**: простое предложение.

Отношение между двумя блоками сложного предложения **причинно-следственные** (союз-частица ***ВЕДЬ***), но их  желательно обозначить  двоеточием или тире **(запятой** недостаточно). Для разговорного стиля подойдет **тире** (без подчеркнутой паузы, как при двоеточии).

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

**О "лопатинских" блоках**

Они удобны в тех случаях, когда желательно использовать тире, то есть обозначит более **сильный знак**, разделив предложение **на две**, а не на три  части.

**Сравним:**

(1) *Ну, я встал в шесть утра, **что** удивительно, ведь свой режим я толком и не наладил.*

**Последовательное** подчинение придаточных? Не думаю. Первые два предложения — это единое целое. Предложение с запятыми звучит **невыразительно, монотонно.** Тире позволяет разделить предложение на два блока, выделив более сильную связь:

(2) *Ну, я встал в шесть утра, **что** удивительно — **ведь** свой режим я толком и не наладил.*

Раздел между блоками лучше сделать по **причинно-следственной** связи (ведь). Также надо учесть, что ***ВЕДЬ*** — это разговорный **союз-частица**, то есть что-то среднее между структурным элементом и полноценным союзом. Поэтому причинное значение желательно дополнить **тире**.

Кроме того, 2-е предложение — это придаточное присоединительное, ***ЧТО*** — союзное слово, вмещающее содержание главного предложения. Эти предложения **разделить нельзя**, между ними сильная связь.

Синтаксическая **синонимия** — это обычное явление. Но из всех вариантов нужно выбрать наиболее подходящий. Другими словами, подобрать такую **форму** (структурную грамматику), которая наилучшим образом выразит **смысл** сказанного.

Comment: спасибо! а вариант с тире перед «это» совсем негоден?

Comment: Думаю, что подойдет еще такой вариант (тоже неплохой): Ну, я встал в шесть утра, и это удивительно – ведь свой режим я толком и не наладил.  Тогда в первом блоке будет сочинительная связь, союз И, Важно уйти от бессоюзной связи и выразить взаимообусловленность 1-го и 2-го предложений. Союз И с этим справится. Тогда 2-е предложение будет выводом из 1-го предложения.

Answer (score 2):

***Ну, я встал в шесть утра, это удивительно, ведь свой режим я толком и не наладил.***

1. *Ну, я встал в шесть утра* - основное предложение.
2. *Это удивительно* - добавочное замечание, вывод по основному предложению.
3. *Ведь свой режим я толком и не наладил* - придаточное причины к добавочному замечанию (удивительно, ***потому что*** свой режим я толком не наладил; *ведь* в значении причинного союза).

В исходнике первое и второе предложения — части сложного бессоюзного предложения:

*Ну, я встал в шесть утра, это удивительно, ведь свой режим я толком и не наладил.*

Можно написать с тире между первым и вторым предложениями, чтобы добавочное замечание сделать более выпуклым; тире будет обозначать в речи небольшую паузу:

*Ну, я встал в шесть утра — это удивительно, ведь свой режим я толком и не наладил.*

Совсем необязательно "уходить" от бессоюзной связи первого и второго предложений в сочинительную или подчинительную связь: бессоюзая связь не такая уж и страшная!

А так, конечно, можно заменить ***это*** на ***что*** - тогда второе предложение превратится в придаточное присоединительное к первому:

*Ну, я встал в шесть утра, что удивительно, ведь свой режим я толком и не наладил.*

Кстати, в этом случае никаких лопатинских "блоков" я тут не вижу, поскольку последнее (причинное) предложение в непосредственную связь вступает только с предшествующим, вторым предложением, но не с первым (*Ну, я встал в шесть утра, ведь свой режим я толком и не наладил* - это не следствие и причина), а стало быть, налицо обычное последовательное подчинение:

Ну, я встал в шесть утра (*каков вывод?*), что удивительно *(почему удивительно?)*, ведь свой режим я толком и не наладил.